# stringByAppending string issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

```
NSString *wantString;
for (id object in [self.wantTypes allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"object %@",[self.wantTypes objectForKey:object]);
    [wantString stringByAppendingString:[self.wantTypes objectForKey:object]];
}
NSLog(@"%@ wantstring",wantString);
```

Logs:

```
Fys1Formel[19004:60b] object Gravitasjon
Fys1Formel[19004:60b] (null) wantstring
```

Why doesn't appendString work? I tried NSString instead of `id`

Comment: Use NSMutableString instead of NSString.

Comment: Try appending outside of your loop and log the result.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Mutable does not work either

Comment: It should work. check answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just your wantstring is nil all the time; 
Try it:

```
  NSString *wantString;
    for (id object in [self.wantTypes allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"object %@",[self.wantTypes objectForKey:object]);
         wantString =  [wantString stringByAppendingString:[self.wantTypes objectForKey:object]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@ wantstring",wantString);
```

Comment: Yeah, kind of this. Had to do wantString = [append... instead of just [wantString append...]! Accepting in a few.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling method to append string but you are not storing or assigning return of that function. SO you need to assign the return of this method:

```
wantString =  [wantString stringByAppendingString:[self.wantTypes objectForKey:object]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to NSMutableString and allocate it. You also should use appendString, stringByAppendingString return new string, doesn't change your current string.

```
NSMutableString *wantString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (id object in [self.wantTypes allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"object %@",[self.wantTypes objectForKey:object]);
    [wantString appendString:[self.wantTypes objectForKey:object]];
}
NSLog(@"%@ wantstring",wantString);
```

Comment: See now try change it to stringByAppendingFormat:

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMuatableString instead, that's the difference between NSString and NSMutableString (Static vs Dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not storing the result. And additional you can check if the string
you want to add have something inside.

Try to do this way:

```
NSString *wantString = @""; // init your string empty
NSString *temp = @"";

for (id object in [self.wantTypes allKeys])
{
    temp = [self.wantTypes objectForKey:object];

    if (temp.lenght > 0)
    {
        wantString = [wantString stringByAppendingString:temp];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",wantString);
```